# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "amount"

Tags: java, jsp, numberformatexception

I want to display data in datatable. I have two table of data. these two table has a given one to many relation. parent is credit and child is debit. when i hit the api then credit table of all data will be shown but debit table data will not shown. how to display debit table of data iwth same data table

i have try with using given below jsp page with like this type -

```
<td><c:out value="${credit.debit.amount}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${credit.debit.description}"></c:out></td>
```

1.userdashboard.jsp

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Credit Debit Account List</h3>
                <c:if test="${!empty creditdebitlist }">
                    <table id="tblcreditdebit" class="table table-striped display table-hover" style="width:100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Cid</th>
                                <th>Opening Balance</th>
                                <th>Debit Total</th>
                                <th>Drawer Total</th>
                                <th>Debit + drawer</th>
                                <th>Today Business</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <c:forEach items="${creditdebitlist}" var="credit">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.cid}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.openingbalance}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.debittotal}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.drawertotal}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.debittotalplusdrawertotal}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.todaybusiness}"/></td>
                                <td><fmt:formatDate value="${credit.date}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.debit.amount}"></c:out></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${credit.debit.description}"></c:out></td>
                                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> | <a href="/user/getCreditDebit?cid=${credit.cid}" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="showAll();">More</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </c:forEach>    
                    </table>
```

2. response getting when i hit the api

```
[
    {
        "cid": 63,
        "openingbalance": 434,
        "date": "2019-09-02",
        "debittotal": 143,
        "drawertotal": 434,
        "debittotalplusdrawertotal": 577,
        "todaybusiness": 143,
        "debit": [
            {
                "did": 64,
                "amount": 100,
                "description": "dfvgg"
            },
            {
                "did": 65,
                "amount": 43,
                "description": "dfgd"
            }
        ],
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdDate": "2019-09-05",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "updatedDate": "2019-09-05"
    },
    {
        "cid": 66,
        "openingbalance": 43243,
        "date": "2019-09-03",
        "debittotal": 3543,
        "drawertotal": 342424,
        "debittotalplusdrawertotal": 345967,
        "todaybusiness": 302724,
        "debit": [
            {
                "did": 67,
                "amount": 3232,
                "description": "asdds"
            },
            {
                "did": 68,
                "amount": 200,
                "description": "sdd"
            },
            {
                "did": 69,
                "amount": 111,
                "description": "asaa"
            }
        ],
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdDate": "2019-09-05",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "updatedDate": "2019-09-05"
    }
]
```

3.controller

```
    @GetMapping("user/creditDebitList")
    public @ResponseBody List<Credit> showCreditDebitList(Credit credit) {
        return creditDebitService.getAllCreditList();
    }
```

4.Credit.java - model

```
package com.rajesh.model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="credit")
public class Credit extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long cid;
    @Column @Order
    private long openingbalance;
    @Column
    private Date date;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long drawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long todaybusiness;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="credit_debit", 
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="c_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="d_id"))
    private List<Debit> debits = new ArrayList<Debit>(Arrays.asList());
    public Credit() {

    }
    public Credit(Long cid, long openingbalance, Date date, long debittotal, long drawertotal,
            long debittotalplusdrawertotal, long todaybusiness, List<Debit> debits) {
        super();
        this.cid = cid;
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
        this.date = date;
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    public Long getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(Long cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public long getOpeningbalance() {
        return openingbalance;
    }
    public void setOpeningbalance(long openingbalance) {
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
    }   
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public long getDebittotal() {
        return debittotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotal(long debittotal) {
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
    }
    public long getDrawertotal() {
        return drawertotal;
    }
    public void setDrawertotal(long drawertotal) {
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
    }
    public long getDebittotalplusdrawertotal() {
        return debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(long debittotalplusdrawertotal) {
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public long getTodaybusiness() {
        return todaybusiness;
    }
    public void setTodaybusiness(long todaybusiness) {
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
    }
    public List<Debit> getDebit() { 
        return debits;
    }   
    public void setDebit(List<Debit> debits) {  
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Credit [cid=" + cid + ", openingbalance =" + openingbalance + ", date=" + date + ", debittotal= " + debittotal + ", debittotalplusdrawertotal=" + debittotalplusdrawertotal + ", todaybusiness=" + todaybusiness + "]";
    }
}
```

5.Debit.java

```
package com.rajesh.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="debit")
public class Debit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long did;
    @Column
    private long amount;
    @Column
    private String description; 
    public long getDid() {
        return did;
    }
    public void setDid(long did) {
        this.did = did;
    }
    public Debit() {

    }
    public Debit(long amount, String description) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(long amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Debit [did=" + did + ", amount =" + amount + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "amount"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-el-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-el-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-el-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-el-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.userdashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f6(userdashboard_jsp.java:1281) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.userdashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(userdashboard_jsp.java:1060) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.userdashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(userdashboard_jsp.java:988) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.userdashboard_jsp._jspService(userdashboard_jsp.java:251) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` you are receiving a String instead of number which Java could not parse.Debug your code, I think solution would be straight forward.

Comment: what is  problem i dont konw but why debit table data is not display. Credit table data is display correctly

Comment: which object is use for display debit data ?

Comment: I agree with the error message. `amount` is not a number, so it will produce a `NumberFormatException`. Your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has been solve this question by using second forEach loop in side my jsp